# Unknown line in loggc output

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have enabled logging of Garbage Collection for my web application using the -Xloggc:/path/to/file option. All the documentation/tutorials online explain what lines like these mean:

```
[GC 4044799K->4039197K(9122624K), 0.2320070 secs]
[GC 7108933K->5064363K(9122624K), 1.2854980 secs]
[Full GC 4832238K->1823552K(9122624K), 8.7740310 secs]
```

But about 7% of the entries look like the ones below and my question is what does it mean?:

```
[GC 6536892K(9122624K), 1.6101470 secs]
[GC 5299301K(9122624K), 0.2458250 secs]
```

And as far as I can find there is no documentation on what this means (I even went to page 2 of Google's results). There is no arrow, so I assume this means that it tried to garbage collect and couldn't. I have no concrete confirmation of this; it is just my assumption.

Edit: I added in real values, but the numbers are really all over the place.

Comment: No idea, but if you replace the numbers by real ones, someone might have a good guess.

Comment: @maartinus I didn't do that at first because I thought real examples would just be a distraction. I have added a few examples and I will try to collect some statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are using CMS GC, and this means, Capacity of tenured generation space is **9122624K** and CMS GC is triggered when space size is **6536892K**.

```
[GC 6536892K(9122624K), 1.6101470 secs]
```

The explanation from Hotspot can be found at this [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/understanding_cms_gc_logs)

Comment: Are you saying that the lines in question match this line from the -XX:+PrintGCDetails option? `40.146: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 26386K(786432K)] 26404K(1048384K), 0.0074495 secs]`

Comment: @John, Yes, and you can verify this by using -XX:+PrintGCDetails to run the application again.

Comment: Yes indeed, ran it through with the extra logging and all the lines are accounted for.